# Not able to create user defined function in Azure Synapse Studio

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I tried to create a user defined function in Synapse using Synapse Studio. I have selected the server name and my custom database in editor ribbon.
In editor,  am getting syntax error "Create Function is Incorrect token."

Even with syntax error when I execute the function, I get an error "Create Function permission denied in database."

Could you please help me how to create function in Synapse? Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are your referring to Dedicated SQL pool or Serverless SQL pool?

Comment: Thanks. I was referring Dedicated SQL pool.

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure the user requires CREATE FUNCTION permission in the database and ALTER permission on the schema in which the function is being created.

Here is an examples to create a function on Azure Synapse Analytics:

Using a scalar-valued user-defined function to change a data type:

This simple function takes a int data type as an input, and returns a decimal(10,2) data type as an output.

[image]

For more details, refer to [CREATE FUNCTION - Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) and [GRANT Schema Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-schema-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: here is correct link for azure synapse Dedicated SQL pool user defined functions  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-sql-data-warehouse?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7